# Applying subsurface modifier gives holes in my mesh. Why?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm working on a cup and when applying a subsurface modifier it puts these holes near the rim of my cup. I've tried dissolving the edge where the holes appear, but that makes my outside cup look jagged. I've also tried merging by distance and flipping normals but no dice. Here's the blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/f0b8780f6461447daf100064e2d2ed2d

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your normals are flipped on this part, Blender tries to smooth between faces that are inverted, go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals, or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Outside*, or *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*.

[image]

Comment: Flipping normals on the inside will flip them on the outside though. Making the outside blue makes the inside red and vice versa.

Comment: Add a *Solidify* modifier. Then you have inside and outside of the cup a surface. Consider to lower the levels of the Subdivision modifier. You have 3 levels for viewport and 2 for rendering. Makes no sense ;-)  Levels 1 & 2 are fine when you switch Shading to *Shade Smooth* in the context menu.

Comment: @Obama2020, do not flip the normals, recalculate them

Comment: @Blunder solid worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: @Obama2020 if answer solved your issue consider mark as Accepted  https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thank you keep this site organized.